# clojure let destructure java collection

Tags: java, clojure

I am new to Clojure and confused by `let` destructuring:

```clj
java.util.ArrayList

(def arr (java.util.ArrayList. [1 2 3 4]))
;; => #'ns/arr
```

while destructuring:

```clj
(let [[a b] arr]
   (+ a b))
;; => 3
```

everything is ok, but:

```clj
(let [{a 0 b 1} arr]
   (+ a b))
;; caught NullPointerException
```

Which points did I ignore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the reason for this behavior by expanding the `let` into a `let*`:

```clj
(macroexpand-1
 '(let [[a b] arr]
    (+ a b)))
;;=> (let* [vec__1 arr
;;          a (clojure.core/nth vec__1 0 nil)
;;          b (clojure.core/nth vec__1 1 nil)]
;;     (+ a b))

(macroexpand-1
 '(let [{a 0 b 1} arr]
    (+ a b)))
;;=> (let* [map__1 arr
;;          map__1 (if (clojure.core/seq? map__1)
;;                   (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create
;;                    (clojure.core/seq map__1))
;;                   map__1)
;;          a (clojure.core/get map__1 0)
;;          b (clojure.core/get map__1 1)]
;;     (+ a b))
```

As you can see, sequential destructuring uses the `nth` function, while associative destructuring uses the `get` function. While `nth` uses the [`clojure.lang.RT/nth`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L892-L949) method, which supports the [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface that `ArrayList` implements, `get` uses [`clojure.lang.RT/get`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L733-L758), which does not support `RandomAccess`. The default case of `get` returns `null`, so that's why you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

Incidentally, because `LinkedList` does not implement `RandomAccess`, this gives an error as well:

```clj
(def linked (java.util.LinkedList. [1 2 3 4]))

(let [[a b] linked]
  (+ a b))
;; java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: LinkedList
```

Comment: You get the same results with a native Clojure list: `(def arr (list 1 2 3 4))`.